# NSIS: Run sub-file of Installation in compatibility mode

Tags: installation, compatibility, nsis

I am using NSIS to create an application installer which consists of multiple programm installation files, mainly .exe and .msi files.

Now I have the problem that I have a very old setup file which only works properly if I set the compatibility to Windows ME/98. Usually the Users which will run the installation don't have the ability to run the whole installation package in compatibility mode.

Is there a command in NSIS to execute such a sub-setup in a specific compatibility mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [__COMPAT_LAYER](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286705) to Win98:

```
System::Call 'Kernel32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t "__COMPAT_LAYER", t "Win98")'
ExecWait '"$instdir\foo.exe"'
System::Call 'Kernel32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t "__COMPAT_LAYER", i 0)'
```

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Needed this when installing vc_redist.x64.exe using NSIS.  Worked like a charm, but used "Win7" instead of Win98.